# Fetching people without a registration for a specific event

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to fetch all people without a registration for a specific event.

My models are Person, Event and Registration.

In the MySQL table it would add an entry to the registrations table with the `person.id` and `event.id` (plus comment and a "status" - 1 for registration, 2 for deregistration).

Now, I'm trying to get all people which did no action, all registrations and all deregistrations (in that order). How can I do that?

*edit:* may I add some more information:

Structure in database:
people: id, name, mail ...
events: id, title, date ...
registrations: id, person_id, event_id, status ...

Problem:
It's easy to select all registrations and deregistrations. But I've also to select all people which did no action for an event.

One way I thought about is to select all people from the people model. Then select all registrations from the specific event, and finally compare the two arrays. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following:

Select all People, then loop through all events and select all people which registered or deregistered. Then subtract them from all people...

That's it.

```
#model
def all_register_people
    registrations = Registration.find_all_by_event_id self.id
    people = []

    for registration in registrations
      people "shift" registration.person
    end

    people
  end

#view
all_people = Person.all(:order => "firstname")

...

register_event_people = event.all_register_people
people_no_action = all_people - register_event_people

people_reg = Person.all(...)
people = people_no_action | people_reg
```

"shift" means "<<"

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby Controller:

```
@persons = Person.all(:order => "status ASC")
```

Comment: This won't work because status is in the model "registrations" and the registration is from a specific event

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort it out in your view you can also use the #select method on all the Person objects:

```
#controller
@people = Person.all

#view
<h2> registered people </h2>
<% @people.select { |person| person.status == 1 }.each do |reg| %>
....
<% end %>

<h2> de-registered people </h2>
<% @people.select { |person| person.status == 2 }.each do |reg| %>
....
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think that wouldn't work, because a person has no or one registration per event. So there are multiple events where a person can register or de-register. If someone registers, it would add a registration for this event with "status=1"

Comment: ok, just shooting from the hip without seeing your code or tests. Instead, of @people = Person.all, I think you could substitute with @people = Event.find(1).people and it would grab just the people for that single event